# WebUSB getDevices empty list

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webusb

Running Chrome 56.0.2924.76 (64-bit) on Windows 10 PRO Version 1511 (OS Build 10586.753). Have enabled experimental-web-platform-features on chrome, running it with flag --disable-webusb-security and as administrator. I try to get USB device list on localhost (using https) with getDevices but I get empty list, although chrome://device-log is showing me plenty of devices. What could be the issue?

```
navigator.usb.getDevices().then(function(devices){
    console.log(devices);
});
// console outputs []
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should use `requestDevice()` before in order to get access permissions on selected devices.

```
navigator.usb.requestDevice({filters:[]}).then(function(device){
   console.log(device);
});
```

After that you'll be able to call `getDevices()`.

Comment: From the Google documentation : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web#get_access_to_usb_devices

Comment: Looks like I did not read it carefully enough because I was following the same article. Thanks.